# Compare 2 fields in where statement ORMLite

Tags: ormlite

Is it possible to compare 2 fields from the table in where condition in ORMLite without using where().raw(statement, args)?

SQL query looks like

```
select 
   * 
from
   table
where 
   table.f1 = table.f2
```

Answer (score 0):

try This ... i hope Its Work For You !!!

```
select (case when (table.f1 = table.f2 ) then 'EQUAL' else 'NOT_EQUAL' end) as one from table
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE f1 LIKE 'f2';
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE f1 = f2;
```

Comment: seems you haven't understood my question. I know how to write SQL-query for this task. I don't know how to do this in ORMLite framework without using "raw()" method.

The third variation in you answer is the same as sql example in my question. What the sence in this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why I missed this last time. ORM Lite [doc](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_3.html#Column-Arguments) contains the answer:

ColumnArg object is designed to compare one column against another.

```
QueryBuilder<Table, String> queryBuilder = tableDao.queryBuilder();
queryBuilder.where().eq(Table.f1,
new ColumnArg(Table.f2));
List<Table> results = queryBuilder.query();
```